# Calling StoredProcedure with Oracle Plsq Index-Table in Java: Alternatives to deprecated set/getPlsqlIndexTable do not work

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to call a simple Oracle Stored-Procedure that takes a plsql-index-table and retursn a plsql-index-table as OUT parameter.
My old approach works perfectly but the methods I used there are deprectad now. That was my old Approach:

```
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
    CallableStatement callableStatement = oracleConnection.prepareCall("BEGIN STORED_PROC_IBT_PACKAGE.SIMPLE_INANDOUT_NUMBER_DEC(?,?); END;");
    OracleCallableStatement oracleCallableStatement = callableStatement.unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class);
    BigDecimal[] input = new BigDecimal[] {BigDecimal.valueOf(1), BigDecimal.valueOf(2),BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,
            BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO};
    
    oracleCallableStatement.setPlsqlIndexTable(1, input,10, input.length,Types.DECIMAL, 10);
    oracleCallableStatement.registerIndexTableOutParameter(2, 10, Types.DECIMAL, 10);
    
    oracleCallableStatement.execute();
    
    BigDecimal[] plsqlIndexTable = (BigDecimal[])oracleCallableStatement.getPlsqlIndexTable(2);
    Arrays.stream(plsqlIndexTable).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I am not sure if my new approach is correct by using an array and using 'setObject', 'getObject' and 'createOracleArray' but it works nearly perfect. My new approach:

```
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
    CallableStatement callableStatement = oracleConnection.prepareCall("BEGIN STORED_PROC_IBT_PACKAGE.SIMPLE_INANDOUT_NUMBER_DEC(?,?); END;");
    OracleCallableStatement oracleCallableStatement = callableStatement.unwrap(OracleCallableStatement.class);
    BigDecimal[] input = new BigDecimal[] {BigDecimal.valueOf(1), BigDecimal.valueOf(2),BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,
            BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO};
    
    oracleCallableStatement.setObject(1, oracleConnection.createOracleArray("DBACCESSTESTDB.STORED_PROC_IBT_PACKAGE.NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX", input));
    oracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "DBACCESSTESTDB.STORED_PROC_IBT_PACKAGE.NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX");

    oracleCallableStatement.execute();

    Array plsqlIndexTable = (Array)oracleCallableStatement.getObject(2);
    BigDecimal[] results = (BigDecimal[])plsqlIndexTable.getArray();
    Arrays.stream(results).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The problem with new approach is that only 9 elements come back instead of 10. The reasons seams to be that the first element (in Java with index 0) is lost somewhere. I don't no if it is lost when sending in to the Stored-Proceudure or when retrieving it. Is this an Oracle Bug or is my new approach somehow wrong?

Edit: Okay now I know that the problems occurs when sending the array to the storedProcedure. When I use the old approach with "setPlsqlIndexTable" for setting the IN-parameter and the new approach ('registerOutParameter' and 'getObject') for retrieving the OUT-parameter it works.
But I still not know how to fix the problem. Still the first element of the array is lost

Comment: Answer & accept your own question so there will be less disappointed readers. Thanks for the insights though.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding - The problem is not fixed yet - I only know that the problem occurs when sending it to the db. The output is still wrong since the first element of the array is missing. I edit my original question so that it is clear that the problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i think I found the problem. My stored-procedure was declared like this:

```
    PROCEDURE SIMPLE_INANDOUT_NUMBER_DEC
(
  NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN IN NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX,
  NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_OUT OUT NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX
)
  AS
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1..NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN.last  loop
        NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_OUT(i) := NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN(i) + 1;
      end loop;
    END SIMPLE_INANDOUT_NUMBER_DEC;
```

With the old approach `setPlSqlIndexTable` it was correct to start with index 1. Starting with index 0 would lead to an **ORA_1403 No-Data**.

With the new approach `('setObject' and 'createOracleArray')` the index in PLSQL starts at 0. So to get it work for both approaches it is best to define the start index with `NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN.first`.

```
    PROCEDURE SIMPLE_INANDOUT_NUMBER_DEC
(
  NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN IN NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX,
  NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_OUT OUT NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX
)
  AS
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN.first..NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN.last  loop
        NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_OUT(i) := NUMBER_TABLE_INDEX_IN(i) + 1;
      end loop;
    END SIMPLE_INANDOUT_NUMBER_DEC;
```

This is the only way that I found, that works for both approaches for me.